# OnTextChanged Event Not Triggering HTTP Post

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox within a C# web Form.  I am trying to use the OnTextChanged event call Some C# code when the textbox loses focus.  As you can see in the code snipit below, I do have AutoPostBack="true" on the text box as was the solution for the vast majority of other issues.

```
<asp:Textbox ID="registryNumberTxt" CssClass="textboxsize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="pullRegNumInfo"/>
```

The server side method, however, does get called when I click a submit button at the bottom of the page.  So, it seems to me that the page is not Posting when the textbox loses focus.

```
protected void pullRegNumInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String registryNumber = registryNumberTxt.Text;
    keywayLbl.Text = regGen.getKeyway(registryNumber);
    pinsLbl.Text = regGen.getNumPins(registryNumber);
}
```

Any help, or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appriciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Any letter key in the textbox, the event will triggered, loses focus never triggered in this case.

Comment: Try removing and then adding the TextBox and pullRegNumInfo method again.

Comment: @VDWWD you were on the right track.  I had copied and pasted this file from another existing file in the project.  I believe there must have been some reference somewhere that was incorrect.  I deleted the while file/page that contained the above mentioned code and added new, and it now works.  The method I have specified in the ontextchanged method now fires when the text has changed and the method loses focus.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to put your debug on page load and than change text than see what's going ?