# LinkButton click event not firing asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I dont know why linkbutton onclick event is not firing. I have tried rewriting the code. I have tried to redirect directly on button click function. I have tried setting a break point inside `dashbut_Click()` on `redirectUser()` line but it never reaches there. Kindly help me figure this out.

**HTML:**

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="dashbut" runat="server" 
           CausesValidation="false" 
           OnClick="dashbut_Click"
           Text="Dashboard">
               <img src="images/dash.png" height="25" width="25" class="fa fa-tachometer" /><span> Dashboard</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
 </li>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void dashbut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Response.Redirect("~/Views/Portal/AdminDashboard.aspx");
    redirectUser();
}

private void redirectUser()
{
    string myConnection = dbController.connectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);

    string userCheckQuery = "SELECT UserType from tblUsers where ID = '" + USERid + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(userCheckQuery, conn);
    conn.Open();
    bool userType = (bool)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();

    if (userType == true)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Views/Portal/AdminDashboard.aspx");
    }
    else if (userType == false)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Views/Portal/Dashboard.aspx");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that the LinkButton click event is not firing because of a JS Error. I dont know how that is related but when I click on the button and view the error on browser Inspect Element I see the following TypeError.

```
Uncaught TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function
at __doPostBack (NewArtist.aspx:63)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

**This is the script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Error is on `theForm.submit();` line.

This is beyond me. Help me out.

Comment: Is your `asp:LinkButton` inside the `form`?

Comment: it would get an error if not

Comment: @PaulAbbott yes it is.

Comment: it doesn't go in to redirectUser ? did you put a break point and see if its throwing some kind of exception or something?

Comment: Yes I tried putting a break point on redirectUser() function call. But when I click on the LinkButton nothing happens. It doesn't redirect nor does it throw an exception

Comment: is your PageLoad event fired when clicking the button?

Comment: @MartinE It is fired when the page loads but not fired when clicking on the button. But PageLoad should fire on button click, right? Why do you think its not?

Comment: Hm, normally the click event is a postback to the server and should trigger the page load event first before handling the click event. Are you using some JS, or a ScriptManager object?

Comment: yes I am using JavaScript, But how is that related to this link button?

Comment: Try removing the LinkButton and the `dashbut_Click` method. Then recreate them. It worked for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490795/ontextchanged-event-not-triggering-http-post#comment70189841_41490795). If not there could be a javascript error/interference somewhere as @MartinE also suggests

Comment: I would like to see all events are not fire or just one button click event. Could you set a break point at Page_Load event, and see it stop?

Comment: @Win Setting a breakpoint on PageLoad event does stop when page loads for the first time but later on when I click on the linbutton it doesn't which means that the event is not firing. As I see it there is something wrong with JS. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MartinE Yes you are right. Its something with JS but I am not sure what. I have updated the question.

Comment: @VDWWD I have recreated the button and function but it seems its JS that is the problem here.

Comment: Well, we are like shooting in the dark without seeing the rest of the code. So, create a new ASPX page *(without master page)*, and add a ***LinkButton*** with ***OnClick*** event, and try debug it?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem seemed to be with JavaScript. Actually there was a button on my page with `ID=submit` this was overriding `submit()` function on the form, hence the error. This [helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript)
Thumbs Up for Stackoverflow Community.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I can't comment due to low reputation points. I would like to know if you need CauseValidation set to false.

Try adding usesubmitbehavior="false".

Comment: I have tried your code and it worked. Is possible that the event is duplicated somewhere else. causing this one not to fire?

Comment: try adding this to your Linkbutton. submitbehavior="false"

Comment: I have updated the question. Uncaught exception in JavaScript is causing the event not to fire